# ValueError: Cannot use Queryset for "": Use a Queryset for ""

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a little project using these models here and I'm trying to figure out a way to get a set of all the posts associated with users the currently authenticated user is following.

But I keep getting:

> Cannot use QuerySet for "Profile": Use a QuerySet for "User".

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    isInstructor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isTutor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isStudent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name = "followers", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    profile_image = ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts")
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name="posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is what keeps giving me the error.

```
current_user = Profile.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
Post.objects.filter(poster__in = current_user.following.all())
```

I searched around an found out that I had to use the __in operator whenever you want to filter by a list of things.  But I keep getting the same error.  Any help with explaining what the error means and what I can do to get around it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried `poster__profile__in` ?

Comment: I wonder if the error would have been clearer if you'd named the variable as `current_profile` rather than `current_user`?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try something like this,

```
Post.objects.filter(poster__id__in=current_user.following.all().values_list('user_id'))
```

Comment: Sorry, this is old, but: shouldn't that be `...values_list('user_id')`? Otherwise you're comparing a `User.id` with `Profile.id`s.

Answer (score 1):

`profile` class is different to the `user class`. Therefore, the Profile instance is different to User's instance.

Instead of use `current_user` you need to use `current_user.user`.

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I do not see a clear explanation of the error yet.

Consider this:

- `Post.poster` is a foreign key to the `User` model.
- `current_user` is a `Profile` object, not, as the name would suggest, a `User` object.
- `Profile.following` is a m2m relation back to `Profile`, so it represents a `Profile` queryset.

Thus, when you filter on `poster__in=current_user.following.all()`, you're actually trying to compare a `User` with a `Profile` queryset.

This cannot be done, and Django is telling you exactly that:

`Cannot use QuerySet for "Profile": Use a QuerySet for "User".`

To fix this, you should provide a `User` queryset in the filter, e.g. something similar to zaidfazil's answer:

```py
current_user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
Post.objects.filter(
    poster__in=current_user_profile.following.values('user_id')
)
```

Or do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247647

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the original post, but may help people who end up here based on the title:

A similar error message can also arise when your lookup refers to a reverse relation using [`'<fieldname>_set'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

For example, if a `Bar` model has a foreign key to a `Foo` model, then `Foo` will get a default [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) called `Foo.bar_set`. However, a lookup attempt like `foo__bar_set__in=...` would yield the following error:

`ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "Bar": Use a QuerySet for "Foo".`

This can be fixed by removing the `_set` from the lookup, so `foo__bar_set__in=...` should actually be `foo__bar__in=...`.