# Django Rest Framework showing ValueError:Cannot use QuerySet for "Post": Use a QuerySet for "Account"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to list and paginate favourite post of users. I got a custom pagination snippet from so, which I am using here, But I am getting this error.
ValueError:Cannot use QuerySet for "Post": Use a QuerySet for "Account".

I guess, there are problems with my serializer or views. can anyone please help me fix this issue?

These are the codes:

serializers:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    post_date = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    comment_set = CommentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id','title', 'post_date', 'user', 'image', 'comment_set']



class PostFavouriteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    favourite = PostSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['favourite',]
```

views

```
class CustomPaginator(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 3

    def generate_response(self, query_set, serializer_obj, request):
        try:
            page_data = self.paginate_queryset(query_set, request)
        except NotFoundError:
            return Response({"error": "No results found for the requested page"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serialized_page = serializer_obj(page_data, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serialized_page.data)

class FavouritePostAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        user = self.request.user
        favourite_posts = Post.objects.filter(favourite=user.post_favourite.all())
        paginator = CustomPaginator()
        response = paginator.generate_response(post, PostFavouriteListSerializer, request)
        return response
```

This is the Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/postimage/', null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date Posted")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_favourite', blank=True)
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\danny\Project\posts\api\views.py" in get
  186.      favourite_posts = Post.objects.filter(favourite=user.post_favourite.all())

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  892.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  910.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1290.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1315.                 child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1224.             self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in check_related_objects
  1079.                 raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/posts/posts/favourites/
Exception Value: Cannot use QuerySet for "Post": Use a QuerySet for "Account".
```

Comment: Unrelated: **`NotFoundError`**? Where that comes from?

Comment: Hello,
This is from from 
rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound as NotFoundError..you need to import this!

Comment: Oh... I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the info. I think you can use [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) instead of `APIView`. That may be more suitable for you to handle the pagination issue.

Comment: But would it work without needing to change anything in my views or serializers? coz the error is something which I can;'t really figure out. It showing I need to use Account model instead of Post as queryset which doesn't make any sense to list all posts..

Comment: can you please check whether my serializers are correctly coded?

Comment: Alsways, add full error traceback if you have got any errors

Comment: add Post models

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question with the traceback and Post model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Cannot use Queryset for "": Use a Queryset for ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827650/valueerror-cannot-use-queryset-for-use-a-queryset-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace :

```
favourite_posts = Post.objects.filter(favourite=user.post_favourite.all())
    paginator = CustomPaginator()
    response = paginator.generate_response(post, PostFavouriteListSerializer, request)
```

by :

```
favourite_posts = user.post_favourite.all()
    paginator = CustomPaginator()
    response = paginator.generate_response(favourite_posts, PostSerializer, request)
```

the related m2m post_favourite is a queryset of post , not need to filter/get this, so you dont need `PostFavouriteListSerializer`

alternative can be this:

```
favourite_posts = Post.objects.filter(favourite=user)
```

you get all post with favourite have your user

Comment: This was how I did first, but with this I was getting another error, which is this one, AttributeError at /api/posts/posts/favourites/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `PostSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Account` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Account' object has no attribute 'title'.

Comment: Sorry, Thank worked.. I forgot to change the serializer first.
Thank you

Comment: retry , and in "paginator.generate_response" you pass "post" but is not define , can be "favourite_posts" ?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo..but before I forgot to change the serializer. This worked like charm!
Thank you