# Django ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "": Use a QuerySet for "User"

Tags: python, django, cs50

I'm working on a project in CS50w where I have to show the posts of the user I'm following and I'm getting the following error

> ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "Following": Use a QuerySet for "User".

**models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """Tracks all the posts"""
    text = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Following(models.Model):
    """Tracks the following of a user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followers")
```

And this how I'm trying to retrieve the posts of the users I'm following:
**views.py**

```
# Gets all the posts from the users the current user is following
followings_usernames = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user)
posts = Post.objects.filter(user=followings_usernames)
```

Comment: This almost looks like a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43827650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter based on a field (`Following.user`) through a reverse relation (`followers`) through the `Post.user` field:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user__followers__user=request.user)
```

See the Django documentation for [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and the usage of double underscores to separate models and fields.

Comment: Thanks. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it might help

```
  # Gets all the posts from the users the current user is following
    followings_usernames = list(Following.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('user', flat=True))
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=followings_usernames)
```