# Using Two Different Models In Views to Return a Newly Created List, Not Already Called Querylist, With a For Loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create the following view:

```py
class FeedAPI(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):

    #lookup_url_kwarg = 'id'
    def get_querylist(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        props = Profile.objects.filter(id=id)
        followers = Profile.filter(followers.includes(props))

        querylist = [
            {'queryset': Profile.objects.filter(followers), 'serializer_class': ProfileSerializer},
            {'queryset': Post.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PostSerializer},
        ]
        feedPosts= []
        for x in followers:
            feedPosts = Posts.objects.filter(Source_id=Post.sourceID)
        return Response(props, feedPosts, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But I get the error `type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'filter'` which according to stack overflow, comes because I am not returning a querylist in my def get_query list. So, I would like to know how I can just return the Post IDs that have the same sourceIDs associated with the followers of a profile. My models are Source, Profile, and Post. Profile and Post have sourceID ForeignKeys.

**Profile model**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, default=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sourceID = models.ForeignKey('Source', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    followers = models.ForeignKey( 'Source', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', default='', blank=True, null=True)
    following = models.ForeignKey('Source', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

***Post model***

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    sourceID = models.ForeignKey('Source', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        "Post Picture", upload_to='post_pics', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

***Source model***

```py
class Source(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Update**
Still no success, still same error. But, I tried making feedPosts in the for statement a list by: `feedPosts = list(Posts.objects.filter(Source_id=Post.sourceID))` and then returning feedPosts, but I have had no success.

**Update #2**
I took the advice from Michal and changed my followers to `followers = [f.pk for f in Profile.objects.filter(followers__includes=props)]` But I am now getting the error: 'Cannot use QuerySet for "Profile": Use a QuerySet for "Source".` I looked at this stackoverflow with the same error: [ValueError: Cannot use Queryset for "": Use a Queryset for ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827650/valueerror-cannot-use-queryset-for-use-a-queryset-for) but I don't see how the solution translates. The purpose of my querylist is just to bring in multiple models. If anyone has a solution to this, or a better suggestion to achieve what I am trying to, please teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Profile` indeed does not have a `filter` method unless you define it yourself. What you need really is the `objects` Manager. After that, you can do whatever you want with the data.

According to the documentation you need to return a list of dictionaries from your `get_querylist` method, not a HttpResponse. That would be your `querylist` variable.

To sort out the `filter` thing and to get a list of IDs, try this:

```py
followers = [f.pk for f in Profile.objects.filter(followers__includes=props)]
```

One last thing. Your `followers` field is a `ForeignKey`, which points to exactly one other thing. Use a `ManyToManyField` for this.

Comment: This fixes the problem with the filtering; however, it brings about a new problem: 'Cannot use QuerySet for "Profile": Use a QuerySet for "Source".' I don't know why this is, and this stack overflow post has the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827650/valueerror-cannot-use-queryset-for-use-a-queryset-for but I don't think the solution to their problem is the same here.

Comment: That’s right, I didn’t notice this when I was writing the response. `followers` field points to the `Source` model, thus you need to provide a `Source` object to filter by. If you don’t need the `props` variable anywhere else, the simplest would be this: `props = Source.objects.filter(profile_id=id)`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However, I'm now getting Source is not defined.

Comment: I thought that would be the issue, so I went back and checked all.  Source is imported from models to serializers to views

Comment: In the line ```props = Source.objects.filter(profile_id=id)```, should I do ```(Profile.sourceID=id)``` instead?

Comment: @AndrewBregman no, definitely not. Those parameters are Django’s filter syntax. Double `_` is basically like a `.` in plain Python. Now that I look at it, you have one FK from `Source` to `Profile` and one the other way. Is that intentional?

Comment: I was just trying to associate the two, giving posts & profiles a sourceID. Do I not need to do this? Why & How do would you bypass this?

Comment: It isn’t necessarily bad, I just don’t know what it means, that’s all. It is _usually_ bad, you don’t want to reference one from the other. It _usually_ doesn’t make much sense, if you try to imagine the database entities like actual real-world things you can have in your hands. This is a bit meta, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231787/discussion-between-andrew-bregman-and-michal-krejci).